# Rails: Commenting for a Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I am creating a website blog and don't know what I'm going to do for adding a comment in a blog. Is there a gem or trick for that? Can you please help me and give me some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "trick" - you just have to code it up like the rest of your application.

---

**Associations**

Since your `comments` will be directly associated to your `posts`, it makes to start by looking at the *association* between the two models:

```
#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end
```

The importance of this association is that if you want to create comments, although they'll be their own individual objects, they'll have to be "tied" to a post. The importance of this lies in the [`object-orientated`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) nature of Ruby / Rails:

--

**OOP**

[image]

Most people don't realize that since Ruby is an *object orientated* language, Rails is also an object-orientated framework.

This means that you need to structure you methods, actions, etc *around* objects. Most beginners think you just have to create a "logical" app flow - whereas the reality is you need to build your app *around* the objects you hope to serve

--

**Resources**

Further to this, you then need to consider how you'll interact with the resources / objects in your application. I would recommend using [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :comments #-> domain.com/posts/5/comments/new
end
```

The reason this is important is because of how you can then create a `comment` with it:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @comment = Comment.new
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :params, :post_id)
   end
end
```

This allows you to use the following:

```
#app/views/comments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :comment_attributes %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will help you create `comment` objects as a child of the `post` objects you want - giving you the ability to create comments for each post.

---

**Bonus**

A bonus here is that if you wanted to then `nest` the comments on your site, you'll want to use the `Ancestry` gem, as follows:

[image]

The way to do this is relatively simple. If you have a comments creation system set up, as outlined above, you'll want to add the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to your `Comment` model:

```
#app/models/comments.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_ancestry
end
```

You'll need to migrate an `ancestry` column to your `comments` datatable, and then be able to populate the `ancestry` attribute:

[image]

You can then use the following partial to show the comments in a `tree` fashion:

```
#app/views/comments/_tree.html.erb
<ol class="categories">
    <% collection.arrange.each do |category, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <div class="category">
                <%= link_to category.title, edit_admin_category_path(category) %>
            </div>

            <!-- Children -->
            <% if category.has_children? %>
                <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
            <% end %>

        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

You can then call it as follows:

```
<%= render partial: "comments/tree", locals: { collecton: @comments } %>
```

Comment: Wow! So great Sir! You deeply explained it very well. And it's very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement external comments engine, such as [Disqus](https://disqus.com/), or keeping it in house by making a Comment resource, which would have a relation to your post, like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

This way you have a right way of treating your comments.

It needs some other work, controllers, views etc... But the spirit is there.

Comment: @rich-peck just went deeper ! Thanks Rich.